# ejabberd: Adding a new user

Tags: ejabberd, mnesia

I would like to know when a new user is added to ejabberd and which event gets triggered.  Also I am not sure in which Mnesia table this information maybe found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new user is created, the hook `register_user` is triggered. This is a `run` hook as defined in [ejabberd hook list](http://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/hooks/):

```
register_user(User, Server) -> ok
```

If you are using Mnesia to store user, the information will be stored in table `passwd`.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out that the user info is stored in the passwd table.